# How to give highlight a View in react native?

Tags: view, react-native

Iam new to RN and currently developing a project. I need to create a highlighting for a view like this like [[the 1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DidL.jpg)],[[this is the design i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwNHM.jpg)],[[code for the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r6w6.jpg)]. The template is then used in the renderitem prop to render the view. Please have a look through this?. Also this highlighting should be given only to the respective box when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Conditional (ternary) operator to change the border color.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```js
class SlotTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ borderColor: this.props.checked ? '#F00' : '#444' }}>
          <CheckBox />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will check that out, also how can I provide highlighting to a box when it's clicked?

Comment: You can do the same. :) Just create a new state instead of props and use Conditional (ternary) operator to change the border-color based on that state.

When you click, you update the state false into true, and vice varsa.

Comment: It did work. But  I guess iam having a problem with updating state from true to false. Currently when i click the boxes each one will be highlighted and the state is maintained.

Comment: Good! Updating the state is already a different topic but here you can take a look at my example code to update the state true to false and false to true... and again and again.

Comment: ```
this.setState((prevState) => !prevState.checked);
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it, i am a noob in coding and recently started learning.

Comment: Alright, you can check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359800/how-to-toggle-boolean-state-of-react-component

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shadowColor` `shadowOffset` properties to give shadow to your view. This link will help you
https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

give this style for second view.

```
<View style={{borderWidth:2, margin:10, padding:10, borderColor:'#444',
                        backgroundColor:'#fff',
                        shadowColor: "#000",
                        shadowOffset: {
                          width: 0,
                          height: 3,
                        },
                        shadowOpacity: 0.29,
                        shadowRadius: 4.65,
                        elevation: 7,
          }}>
<Text>Sample Text</Text>
```