# React useState hook uses the initial state value and ignores the update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have written a component like below where I use React.useState to control the logic to show the button.

If I click the button, it will reveal a sub-button, which was hidden initially, then, if I click on the sub button, it will reveal some content, but the second operation never gets executed.

Below is the code:

MyButton code:

```
    export default observer(function MyButton() {
       ...
       const [subButtonHidden, setSubButtonHidden] = React.useState<boolean>(true)
       ...
       const onClickSubButton = () => {
           if (!subButtonHidden) {
              displaySubButtonContent(); // never ever reach here
           }
           setSubButtonHidden(!subButtonHidden);
       }

       return (
          <Subbutton
            ...
            subButtonHidden={subButtonHidden}
            onClickSubButton={onClickSubButton}
          />
       ); 
});
```

SubButton code:

```
export default observer(function SubButton(props: ...) {
    ....
    const onClickSubButton = React.useCallback(() => {
        props.onClickSubButton();
    }, []);
    ....
    
    return props.subButtonHidden ? null : (<div>...</div>);
}
```

It turns out that subButtonHidden can be successfully updated as false for the very first click, hence show the sub button, but if I click the sub button, subButtonHidden will be somehow reset to true, if I click on the sub button again, subButtonHidden will still be true, even setSubButtonHidden(false) has been executed, no matter what it just doesn't take the updated values. Why is it behaving like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Subbutton`, you have wrapped the `onClickSubButton` with `useCallback` with no dependencies. That means its never changed. and that means `props.onClickSubButton` is never changed inside the `onClickSubButton`.

So when the first time it is clicked, `subButtonHidden` is found as true and is set to false. When you click the second time, since `onClickSubButton` is not updated because of useCallback, that means the same `props.onClickSubButton` was called in which `subButtonHidden` was true(because of closures).

So removing the `useCallback` around `onClickSubButton` should solve your issue.

Comment: got it. I found that in the actual code it is using something like  const onClickSubButton = React.useCallback(() => {
        props.onClickSubButton(123);
    }, [123]); so it is a constant in the deps and not being updated for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just changing it directly that one time. Instead you should
`setSubButtonHidden(prev => !prev);`

it should change depending on what it is (or was) not just directly changing it that one time from its original.

[How to toggle boolean state of react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359800/how-to-toggle-boolean-state-of-react-component)